# Составление календаря футбольного чемпионата на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Суть задачи такова:
Пусть у нас есть **чётное число N команд**. Требуется составить календарь игр, который будет удовлетворять следующим условиям:

1. Команды играют по **круговой системе** (каждая играет с каждой)
2. Календарь поделен на **туры** (которых, очевидно, будет **N-1**)
3. Каждая команда играет строго **одну игру за тур**

Пишу сюда впервые, изучаю Python совсем недавно. На первый взгляд задача очень простая, но корректно накодить у меня не получается. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализация на Питоне round-robin алгоритма из [@MBo ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859834/23044):

```
import collections 

teams = "ABCDEF"
n = len(teams)
tail = collections.deque(teams[1:n//2] + teams[n//2:][::-1])
for _ in range(len(tail)):
    print_round(teams[0], *tail)
    tail.rotate()
```

где `print_round()` показывает текущий тур:

```
def print_round(*teams, sep='\n'):
    n = len(teams)
    print(*teams[:n//2])
    print(*teams[n//2:][::-1])
    print(end=sep)
```

#### Результат

```
A B C
D E F

A D B
E F C

A E D
F C B

A F E
C B D

A C F
B D E
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def print_round(*teams, sep='\n'):
    n = len(teams)
    print(*teams[:n//2])
    print(*teams[n//2:][::-1])
    print(end=sep)
    
from browser import document
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    teams = list(document['teams'].value.strip())
    n = len(teams)
    tail = teams[1:n//2] + teams[n//2:][::-1]
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        print_round(teams[0], *tail)
        tail[0], tail[1:] = tail[-1], tail[:-1]
on_click('dummy on start')    
</script><label for="teams">teams&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="teams" value="ABCDEF"><button id="mybutton">Составить календарь</button></body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Для организации такого календаря есть round-robin tournament алгоритм.

Выстраиваем команды в две строки

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
```

В каждом туре команда из верхней строки играет с соответствующей нижней.
Для  перехода к следующему туру циклически сдвигаем все команды, кроме первой (её положение всегда фиксировано)

```
A   B ->  C
   ^      |
  /       v
D <- E <- F
```

Получается

```
A   D   B
E   F   C
```

Повторяем сдвиги N-1 раз
Удачи в кодировании.

Comment: спасибо большое! не думал, что всё настолько просто!

Comment: @HerrK удобно крутить с помощью `collections.deque` rotate() метода.